# Date format not displaying in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to format and show the date into a paragraph element. I cant figure out why its not showing the result in the "p" element. This example is trying to format it to the UTC format.

[example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g85vbp9/)

html:

```
<p id="first_time"></p>
```

javascript:

```
function FirstTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toUTCString();
    document.getElementById("first_time").innerHTML = n;
}
```

overall my goal is to take the current date and format it into 2 long and 2 short formats. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the function:

```
// Defines the function, but this doesn't call it
function FirstTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toUTCString();
    document.getElementById("first_time").innerHTML = n;
}
// Calls function
FirstTime();
```